# Using pkg add with a NanoBSD image

Tags: freebsd, java

I'm running into a problem on a NanoBSD installation where I cannot install OpenJDK7 via `pkg add` because it first saves to either `/tmp` or `/var` (not sure which) and on a NanoBSD installation, there is not enough space in this particular location. Can someone please help me either modify `pkg add` or recommend a different way to install OpenJDK7 on NanoBSD.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to control the path's where `pgk_add` stores the temporary files. You can read how to do this [here](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg_add&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html#end) (Environment section). Basically you can adjust the environment variables : `PKG_PATH`, `PKG_DBDIR`, `PKG_TMPDIR` and `TMPDIR`.

Might do the trick!

Best regards,

multimho